# Would like my bookmark action to work and stay on same page not render a new page, unsure of the right link_to helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have created a bookmark action which kind of works however when I click "bookmark" or "unbookmark" it takes me to the show page which is not what I want, I would just like the icon I have clicked to change when I click on "bookmark" and "unbookmark" and stay on the same page (which is the index page). I have looked at other similar questions but they do not make sense to me, I saw that I may have to use something called AJAX however I am new to Ruby and not sure how to use this..

Here is my code, I think the issue is something to do with my link_to  but I am not sure.

Thanks

index.html.erb file:

```
<div id="bookmark">
              <% saved_hairstyle = SavedHairstyle.find_by(user: current_user, hairstyle: hairstyle.id) %>
              <% if saved_hairstyle %>
                <%= link_to saved_hairstyle_path(saved_hairstyle), method: :delete, remote: true do %>
                <!--bookmarked-->
                  <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
                <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <%= link_to hairstyle_saved_hairstyles_path(hairstyle), method: :post, remote: true do %>
                <!--un bookmarked-->
                  <i class="far fa-bookmark"></i>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
```

saved_hairstyles controller:

```
class SavedHairstylesController < ApplicationController
include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:create, :destroy]

  def create    
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])   
    @saved_hairstyle = SavedHairstyle.new(user: current_user, hairstyle: @hairstyle)   
    if @saved_hairstyle.save
      respond_to do |format|         
        format.html { redirect_to hairstyle_path(@saved_hairstyle.hairstyle) }
        format.js  # <-- will render`app/views/saved_hairstyles/create.js.erb`
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'hairstyles' }
        format.js  
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy

    @saved_hairstyle = SavedHairstyle.find(params[:id])

    @saved_hairstyle.destroy
    @hairstyle = @saved_hairstyle.hairstyle
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to hairstyle_path(@saved_hairstyle.hairstyle)}
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb file which executes when someone bookmarks a hairstyle:

```
plusCircle = document.getElementById("bookmark");
plusCircle.innerHTML = `<%= link_to  hairstyle_saved_hairstyles_path(hairstyle), method: :delete do %>
                    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                 <% end %>`
```

Comment: You basically need to use AJAX. First checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBxVN7U1Qsk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hMp2SAsWXw to get and idea how AJAX work which will help you out to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello Amit, I had a look at the videos to understand the basic concept of AJAX. I understand what it does however I am unsure where I am going wrong. I have added ``remote: true`` to my links but it doesn't change anything. My CREATE and DELETE methods are working in my controller as I can see it in the console, (there aren't any errors), however the``create.js.erb `` does not work unless I refresh the page manually. Is there any more guidance you can give? Thanks here is a video for ease of understanding: https://www.loom.com/share/4b4539d3d1cc46f8b1f0c7208516f559

Comment: You could try a boolean flag in your controller. That could change form to false and vice versa.  And reference that variable in your view.

Comment: Why you have used back ticks `` in `<%= link_to...` expression of create.js.erb? Also can you please share what response you receive in the network tab as well?

Comment: Hello @AmitPatel I used back ticks because I thought this is what I had to do when writing Javascript interpolation. Also the response I receive in the network tab is status code 200 OK. There are no errors in the Network tab the function works fine it's just when I click my bookmark I have to refresh the page manually to actually see the change in icon - Annoying - See my video here if you can : https://www.loom.com/share/4b4539d3d1cc46f8b1f0c7208516f559

Comment: first replace back ticks with double quotes and send me video again especially I want to see response body not just response code.

Comment: hi @AmitPatel when I change to double quotes the code does not like it, in the console it says syntax error you will be able to see in the video: https://www.loom.com/share/108a563bad3f4233bfc330be349bfa98 However the CREATE and DESTROY the functions still run... When I changed the quotes back to backticks I didn't get the syntax error, however the page refresh doesn't work still. Here is my repo for ease of understanding too :https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do

Comment: Hum...because there are `"fas fa-plus-circle"` double quotes already there. Try simply single quotes. Meanwhile I am checking your codebase.

Comment: OK Thanks I tried single quotes but the same behaviour still happens, thank you in advance for checking my code.

Comment: @AngelaInniss there is lot of improvement required in the codebase. I don't have that bandwidth but I will help you fix the bookmark issue. You can DM me on https://twitter.com/amit_savani and I would see if I can be help

Comment: @Amit ok I will follow you and contact you today. When you say improvement do you mean streamlining and refactoring my code? I will refactor today although I still like to do things the long way around as I am still learning, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with implementation. It woudn't be feasible to explain the solution.

I have created a PR https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do/pull/35 which would help you to understand.

Feel free to add PR comments if you want to understand the changes. Also you can reach out to me on https://twitter.com/amit_savani in case you still face issue with bookmarking